# SQL relate 4 one to many tables

Tags: sql, relationship

I have the following query which is not giving me my desired output:

```
   SELECT DBO.[PLAN].DATE, 
       DBO.TBRECEIPT.RECEIPTDATE, 
       DBO.TBRECEIPTLINE.RECEIPTQTY, 
       DBO.PLAN_LINE.PALLETS 
FROM   DBO.TBRECEIPT 
       INNER JOIN DBO.TBRECEIPTLINE 
               ON DBO.TBRECEIPT.PKID = DBO.TBRECEIPTLINE.RECEIPTID 
       INNER JOIN DBO.[PLAN] 
                  INNER JOIN DBO.PLAN_LINE 
                          ON DBO.[PLAN].PKID = DBO.PLAN_LINE.PLANID 
               ON DBO.TBRECEIPT.RECEIPTDATE = DBO.[PLAN].DATE
```

I must be relating these 2 sets of header/line tables incorrectly.
Can anyone spot the error?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DBO.[PLAN].DATE, 
       DBO.TBRECEIPT.RECEIPTDATE, 
       DBO.TBRECEIPTLINE.RECEIPTQTY, 
       DBO.PLAN_LINE.PALLETS 
FROM   DBO.TBRECEIPT 
       INNER JOIN DBO.TBRECEIPTLINE 
               ON DBO.TBRECEIPT.PKID = DBO.TBRECEIPTLINE.RECEIPTID 
       INNER JOIN DBO.[PLAN] 
                  --No Condition? Problem 
                  INNER JOIN DBO.PLAN_LINE 
                          ON DBO.[PLAN].PKID = DBO.PLAN_LINE.PLANID 
               ON DBO.TBRECEIPT.RECEIPTDATE = DBO.[PLAN].DATE
```

Try this: I will Recommend you to please use **ALIAS** for table for better code practices.

```
SELECT P.DATE, 
       R.RECEIPTDATE, 
       RL.RECEIPTQTY, 
       PL.PALLETS 
FROM   DBO.TBRECEIPT R 
       INNER JOIN DBO.TBRECEIPTLINE RL 
               ON R.PKID = RL.RECEIPTID 
       INNER JOIN DBO.[PLAN] P 
               ON R.RECEIPTDATE = P.DATE 
       INNER JOIN DBO.PLAN_LINE PL 
               ON P.PKID = PL.PLANID
```

Comment: I have run this query and it executes however does not give me an output.  Can you identify another issue here?

Comment: @endless112 Can u provide some dummy data and your expected output?

Comment: Luv, the purpose of this table is to show a view where planned production is compared to actual production. Tables are as stated above (Receipt/Receiptline, Plan/PlanLine).  I'm looking to join them at date/receiptdate and when I attempt that the query executes however does not give me an output.  Even when I run the query as set out above, no luck.  Does this mean there is something wrong with my table setup, where is a good place to start looking.  If I was to provide a screenshot, what would help most?